# Grid not updating after ajaxcall

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm creating my own filter. The filter has a dropdownlist, when this dropdownlist changes jquery will make an ajaxcall to the corresponding HTTPPOST - controller action. In this action I filter the list and pass it through to my view.

Once the list has reached my view, the webgrid is not updating. Here is some code with some debug information to show what's happening.

### Controller

normal action

```
    public ActionResult Projects() 
    {
        IEnumerable<Project> projects = Adapter.ProjectRepository.Get();
        int test = projects.Count();
        List<ProjectsDisplayViewmodel> projectsView = new List<ProjectsDisplayViewmodel>();
        string strCats = "";
        foreach (Project prj in projects)
        {
            strCats = "";
            Mapper.CreateMap<Project, ProjectsDisplayViewmodel>();
            ProjectsDisplayViewmodel newProject = Mapper.Map<Project, ProjectsDisplayViewmodel>(prj);
            foreach (Category cat in prj.Categories) 
            {
                strCats += cat.CategoryName + ", ";
            }
            newProject.strCategories = strCats;
            projectsView.Add(newProject);
        }

        ViewBag.Categories = new SelectList(Adapter.CategoryRepository.Get(), "CategoryID", "CategoryName");

       /*projectsview contains 4 projects now*/
        return View(projectsView);
    }
```

httppost action

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Projects(string catID, string strSearch)
        {
            IEnumerable<Project> projects = Adapter.ProjectRepository
                                                        .Get()
                                                        .Where(x => 
                                                            x.Categories.Any(
                                                                c => 
                                                                    c.CategoryID == Convert.ToInt16(19))

                                                    );
        int test = projects.Count();

        List<ProjectsDisplayViewmodel> projectsView = new List<ProjectsDisplayViewmodel>();
        string strCats = "";
        foreach (Project prj in projects)
        {
            strCats = "";
            Mapper.CreateMap<Project, ProjectsDisplayViewmodel>();
            ProjectsDisplayViewmodel newProject = Mapper.Map<Project, ProjectsDisplayViewmodel>(prj);
            foreach (Category cat in prj.Categories)
            {
                strCats += cat.CategoryName + ", ";
            }
            newProject.strCategories = strCats;
            projectsView.Add(newProject);
        }

        ViewBag.Categories = new SelectList(Adapter.CategoryRepository.Get(), "CategoryID", "CategoryName");

       /*projectsview contains 1 project now AND WILL DISPLAY 4*/
        return View(projectsView);
    }
```

### project.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<Freelauncher.Models.ProjectsDisplayViewmodel>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Projects";
}

@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 25, 
    selectionFieldName: "selectedRow",ajaxUpdateContainerId: "gridContent");
        grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.NextPrevious);
} 

<h2>Alle projecten</h2>

@Html.DropDownList("Categories", (SelectList) ViewBag.Categories)

<div id="gridContent">
    @grid.GetHtml(
            columns: grid.Columns(
            grid.Column("ProjectTitle", "Titel"),
            grid.Column("ProjectDeadlineDate", "project deadline"),
            grid.Column("ProjectEndRegisterDate", "Registreer deadline"),
            grid.Column("ProjectBudget", "Prijs"),
            grid.Column("ProjectIsFixedPrice", "Vaste prijs"),
            grid.Column("strCategories","Categorieën"),
            grid.Column("ProjectID", "meer info", format: (item) => Html.ActionLink("info", "project", new { Id = item.ProjectID} ))
            //grid.Column("ProjectID", "meer info", format: Html.ActionLink("info", "project", new { Id = }
     ))
</div>
```

What am I missing that the project list in my view is not updated, the correct data is passed to the view....

### edit

The ajax call

```
$("#Categories").change(function () {
    var param = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Project/Projects",
        data: { catID: $(this).val(), strSearch: 'test' },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) { console.log("succes"); },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {console.log("error"); }
    });
});
```

I just noticed that nothing is printed in my console.log.... Not the success neither the error function.

Comment: Could you show the code where you are making the AJAX call? Or is it an `Ajax.BeginForm`?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I think it is the WebGrid that is handling it.

Comment: Did you checked out the Chrome/Firefox/IE console for errors? If the post is reaching the server, could be an empty response or any java script error!

Comment: @DarinDimitrov the I added the ajaxcall in the edit... In my console there are no errors...

Comment: Yes, I see. But you don't do anything in your success callback other than outputing the result to the console. You need to have your controller action return a partial containing the updated grid that you should reinject into the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be doing anything in the `success` callback of your AJAX request (other than  a `console.log` call). So it's perfectly normal that nothing updates. You need to manually update your DOM if you want this to happen.

So you should modify your `HttpPost` controller action so that it returns a PartialView containing the grid. And then in your success callback inject the newly received partial into the DOM:

```
success: function (response) { 
    $('#some_id_of_a_containing_div').html(response);
    console.log("succes"); 
},
```

In this example you should wrap the partial view into a containing div which will get updated here:

```
<div id="some_id_of_a_containing_div">
    @Html.Partial("Partial_Containing_Your_Grid")
</div>
```

Comment: Hmmm, I don't get why i need to modify the html in jquery... I suspected that the view I'm returning with the list would automatically change the webgrid...

Comment: Oh no, nothing will automatically update. You are making an AJAX request to a controller action that returns something (a view in your case) but you should do something with the result in your success callback. Otherwise don't expect anything to happen. Right now you are just making a fire-and-forget call discarding the results. The fact that you have returned a View from your controller action doesn't mean that your page will automatically update. jQuery doesn't know anything about Views. It doesn't even know anything about ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will give it a try. Have to go now, will post tomorrow if it worked, or what my problem is. Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the ajaxcall I receive an error, so the ajax executes the error function instead of the succes function... What could be the problem? The return value of my controller is : 
            return View(projectsView); And there are no errors in my controller

Comment: Are you sure that the view exists? Look in FireBug the exact response from the server.